# Stop regular expression from matching across lines

Tags: java, regex

I have a regular expression,

```
end\\s+[a-zA-Z]{1}[a-zA-Z_0-9]
```

which is supposed to match a line with the specifications

```
end abcdef123
```

where `abcdef123` must start with a letter and subsequent alphanumeric characters.

However currently it is also matching this

```
foobar barfooend
bar fred bob
```

It's picking up that `end` at the end of `barfooend` and also picking up `bar` in effect returning `end bar` as a legitimate result.

I tried

```
^end\\s+[a-zA-Z]{1}[a-zA-Z_0-9]
```

but that doesn't seem to work at all. It ends up matching nothing.
It should be fairly simple but I can't seem to nut it out.

Comment: you should really start using [regex101.com](http://regex101.com) to test and debug your regular expressions

Comment: Are you trying to check if your string has substring that will match your regex, or you want to check if entire string matches regex, or maybe something else?

Comment: I don't understand how is matching the second string, there is something between `end` and `bar`? there should be a `\n`

Comment: you can use [`Pattern.MULTILINE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#MULTILINE) to make `^` and `$` match line start/end instead of input start/end.

Answer (score 12):

`\s` includes also newline characters. So you either need to specify a character class that has only the wanted whitespace charaters or exclude the not wanted.

Use instead of `\\s+` one of those:

- `[^\\S\r\n]` this includes all whitespace but not `\r` and `\n`. [See `end[^\S\r\n]+[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z_0-9]+` here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?36ce2)
- `[ \t]` this includes only space and tab. [See `end[ \t]+[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z_0-9]+` here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?36ce5)

Comment: Seriously, +1 for the fact that \s includes newline.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `\b` (word boundary detection) to check a word boundary. In our case we will use it to match the beginning of the word end. It can also be used to match the end of a word.

As @nhahtdh stated in his comment the `{1}` is redundant as `[a-zA-Z]` already matches one letter in the given range.

Also your regex does not do what you want because it only matches one alphanumeric character after the first letter. Add a `+` at the end (for one or more times) or `*` (for zero or more times).

This should work:

`"\\bend\\s+[a-zA-Z]{1}[a-zA-Z_0-9]*"`

**Edit :** I think `\b` is better than `^` because the latter only matches the beginning of a line.

For example take this input : "end azd123 end bfg456" There will be only one match for `^` when `\b` will help matching both.

Comment: `\b` word boundary checks for boundary between word and non-word characters (word character as defined by `\w`). It is not limited to "beginning" of a word. Another thing is that `{1}` is totally redundant.

Answer (score 0):

Try the regular expression:

```
end[ ]+[a-zA-Z]\w+
```

`\w` is a word character: `[a-zA-Z_0-9]`